# Could not resolve dependencies for project from workspace

Tags: maven

Hi I have a problem with maven. I want to run my app but when I am  typing "clean install jetty:run" I am getting this error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building frontend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The POM for laud.b2b:logic:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.585s
    [INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 13 20:17:27 CEST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Frontend: Could not resolve dependencies for project laud.b2b:Frontend:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find laud.b2b:logic:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

"logic" is a second project in my workspace. 
I don`t know what to do to resolve this error. I've searched whole internet and I can do nothing with it...

My pom.xml from Frontend project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>laud.b2b-root</artifactId>
        <groupId>laud.b2b</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>laud.b2b</groupId>
    <artifactId>Frontend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>frontend</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <vaadin.version>7.1.0</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Needed when using the widgetset optimizer (custom ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory). 
            For widgetset compilation, vaadin-client-compiler is automatically added 
            on the compilation classpath by vaadin-maven-plugin so normally there is 
            no need for an explicit dependency. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>laud.b2b</groupId>
            <artifactId>logic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.xpoft.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-vaadin-integration</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>compile-widgetset</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
                    <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                            <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
                            <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This 
                                way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
                            <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                            <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
                            <noServer>true</noServer>
                            <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                            <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                            <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                            <style>OBF</style>
                            <strict>true</strict>
                            <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <configuration></configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>clean</goal>
                                    <goal>resources</goal>
                                    <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                    <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                    <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[7.1.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

(AD2)

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building frontend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ Frontend ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\mateu\git\LPMavenProblem\laud\laud.b2b-root\Frontend\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Frontend ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\mateu\git\LPMavenProblem\laud\laud.b2b-root\Frontend\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Frontend ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\mateu\git\LPMavenProblem\laud\laud.b2b-root\Frontend\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.744s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 13 21:13:52 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project Frontend: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Paste in you `pom.xml`.

Comment: @Grzegorz- Now my pom file is in question

Comment: Have you done "mvn clean install" for logic project?  It is not finding that Jar in your local repo.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you haven't installed all the dependencies you need to build the `frontend` artifact. If `frontend` depends on `laud.b2b.logic`, you must first install this artifact to your local repository before you can build artifacts that depend on it, i.e.:

1. Go to the `logic` source tree and execute `mvn install`
2. Then go to the `frontend` and try the build process again

Maybe it's a good idea to create a root `pom.xml` for all sub-projects and specify them as modules, then start the build process from the new root project. Maven will compile and install them in the correct order.

**References:**

- [Multi-module projects in Maven](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Comment: Have you installed **JDK** 7? It seems that just a JRE is present on your system.

Comment: I have installed JRE 1.7 and JRE 1.7